# Replication in DataGridView ( vb.net and ms-access database)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Each time i execute it, it replicates the data with new value and appends it to the previous contents of the DatagridView.. I wanna clear the content and then add new values.. Can someone help me please??
This is my code:

```
Private Sub lvTable_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvTable.ItemChecked
    Try

        If lvTable.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Dim Condition As String = ""
            Dim Condition1 As String = ""
            For I = 0 To lvTable.CheckedItems.Count - 1

                Condition += String.Format("'{0}',", lvTable.CheckedItems(I).Text)
                Condition1 += String.Format("'{0}',", lvTable.CheckedItems(I).SubItems(1).Text)
            Next
            Condition = Condition.Substring(0, Condition.Length - 1)
            Condition1 = Condition1.Substring(0, Condition1.Length - 1)
            DataGridView2.Visible = True
            con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim OleDb As String = "Select Item_ID,DishName, SUM(Qty), KOTGenerationItems.Rate, SUM(Amount), DiscPer, SUM(Disc), VATPer, SUM(VATAmt), STPer, SUM(STAmt), SCPer, SUM(SCAmt), SUM(TotalAmt),TableNo,GroupName from KOTGeneration,KOTGenerationItems,Dish where KOTGeneration.TicketID=KOTGenerationItems.Ticket_ID and KOTGenerationItems.Item_ID=Dish.ItemID and TableNo in (" & Condition & ") and GroupName in (" & Condition1 & ")   group by Item_ID,DishName,KOTGenerationItems.Rate,DiscPer,VATPer,STPer,SCPer,TableNo,GroupName order by TableNo"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(OleDb, con)
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
            While (rdr.Read() = True)
                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2), rdr(3), rdr(4), rdr(5), rdr(6), rdr(7), rdr(8), rdr(9), rdr(10), rdr(11), rdr(12), rdr(13), rdr(14), rdr(15))
            End While
            con.Close()
            txtCash.Text = "0.00"
            TotalCalc1()
            Calc()
        Else
            Clear()
            DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView2.Visible = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What do `TotalCalc1()` and `Calc()` do? Could you provide the code for those two `subs`?

Comment: Sub Calc()
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim num As Decimal
            num = Val(txtCash.Text) - Val(txtGrandTotal.Text)
            num = Math.Round(num, 2)
            If num < 0 Then
                txtChange.Text = "0.00"
            Else
                txtChange.Text = num
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: It just calculate the values.